# Keeping a window active/open with automation question

Tags: automation

I have software I use, but the problem with it is it times out after 5 minutes due to inactivity. That's the way it is. I'd like to know if there's a way to make a script to respond to keep the session open. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt is what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you Need help with the Script?